# Mac mini (Late 2014) and 4K TVs

Tags: mac-mini, hdmi, display

Based on [Apple's documentation](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202856), my Mac mini (Late 2014, mid-range model with Intel Iris) should be able to support 4K video through HDMI.  I've plugged in my Seiki 39" 4K TV (SE39UY04), but when the "Best for display" option is chosen, it outputs 1080p, rather than 2160p.  If I choose "Scaled" for the resolution, the only options are 1080p, 1080i, 900p, and 720p.

How can I force the Mac mini to output at 2160p?  Or is Apple's marketing wrong and I bought a machine that doesn't actually [support 4K over HDMI](http://www.apple.com/mac-mini/specs/)?

Edit:  Apparently, it really is an [Apple-acknowledged issue](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6654148), but they've stubbornly not provided any fix.  Frustrating.

Summary: Yosemite reads the EDID from the TV that clearly indicates it supports 4K @ 30Hz, and promptly throws it away considering it invalid because it erroneously thinks the pixel clock to be too high (297 MHz).  Once you fix that, though, there's yet another bug in the frame buffer.  Apparently others online have success in Mavericks and it fails in Yosemite and also no problems at all under Windows.  I'm going to try both of those this week, but ... ugh.

Also... since the comments indicated that perhaps it had to do with the cable or the TV, I should note that during the initial boot (Apple logo with progress bar), the output is correctly set to 2160p@30Hz.  Likewise if I boot while holding down option, when presented with the options for drives to boot from, that screen is outputed at 2160p@30Hz.  But the moment the login screen is presented, it switches back to 1080p@60Hz.

Comment: did you hold the alt key before hitting Scale to show all options

Comment: @Buscar웃 Just tried that, the additional options are 1440x900, 1344x1008, 1344x756, 1280x960, 1024x768, 1024x576, 800x600, 720x576, 640x480.  No 2160p / 4K, though.

Comment: I do not see your Seiki as model listed in the supported list?

Comment: @Buscar웃 That list is for 4K over DP (For TVs that have DP ports), not over HDMI.

Comment: Did you check it's an HDMI 1.4 cable? & that the TV can do 2160 at 30Hz?

Comment: @Tetsujin It is an HDMI 2.0 cable.

Comment: ...& that the TV can do 2160 at 30Hz?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, it can.

Comment: hmmm… then best guess would be the screen isn't correctly reporting its capabilities to the Mac. Maybe something like [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com) might help

Comment: @Tetsujin it apparently reports it okay in this tutorial from MacWorld http://www.macworld.com/article/2598045/really-big-monitors-add-a-4k-display-to-your-mac.html and on other articles I've read, it reports itself as 4K for a variety of Hz (30 or less) to Windows. No luck so far with SRX

Comment: I filed a bug report and Apple listed it as a duplicate.  It's open, and my guess won't ever get any attention (my previous bug reports including ones causing masssive data loss have gone years without ever being fixed)

Comment: My mini showed additional resolutions when I connected it to a Samsung 4K display via Thunderbolt/miniDP to HDMI adapter. Are  your mac settings configured to mirror the screen or act as a second monitor. Have you had any luck getting it to work at 24Hz?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the final solution on that thread?

"Final update. Got my new 2014 Mac Mini now, works w/o problem with my 4k Hisense TV now.

Maybe, worth a note ...

Initially, boots in 4k but then switches to 1080p after the OS is loaded.
To get 4k at the OS level, one has to do this:
1. Switch to 24Hz, 25Hz or 30Hz under Scaling
2. Now, the 2160p resolution emerges in the list (3840x2160)
3. Select it
4. Note how 50Hz and 60Hz now disappeared from the list

It is straightforward to do. But maybe not as intuitive to everybody as Apple may think."

Answer (score 0):

OSX has a pixel-clock-limit at 165hz that you can overclock.   You'll need to patch that with https://github.com/vinc3m1/mac-pixel-clock-patch